# AttributeError at /posts/add/ 'PostForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'

Tags: django

Tenho uma classe PostForm com um método is_valid que valida os campos do formulário, mas ele não está reconhecendo o atributo cleaned_data, sempre que eu tento adicionar um novo post acontece isso:

```
AttributeError at /posts/add/ 
'PostForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'
```

**PostForm**

```
class PostForm(forms.Form):
image = forms.ImageField(required=False)
content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, required=False)

def is_valid(self):
    valid = True
    image = self.cleaned_data.get('image')
    content = self.cleaned_data.get('content')

    if image is None and content is None:
        self.add_error('Seu post precisa de um texto e/ou uma imagem')
        valid = False

    return valid

def add_error(self, message):
    errors = self._errors.setdefault(forms.forms.NON_FIELD_ERRORS, forms.utils.ErrorList())
    errors.append(message)
```

**View**

```
@login_required
def add_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if form.is_valid():
        data_form = form.cleaned_data
        Post.objects.create(image=data_form['image'], content=data_form['content'], user=request.user)

        return redirect('index')

else:
    return redirect('index')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `cleaned_data` só existe depois que o `is_valid()` é chamado.

No seu caso vc está sobre escrevendo o método e executando aqui:

`image = self.cleaned_data.get('image')`

Só que nesse momento vc não chamou o `super` ainda (e nem está chamando).

```
class PostForm(forms.Form):
    image = forms.ImageField(required=False)
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, required=False)

    def is_valid(self):
        valid = super(PostForm, self).is_valid()

        if not valid:
            return valid

        # Aqui vai o resto do seu código
```

Depois que o super for executado o `cheaned_data` poderá ser usado.

Comment: Era exatamente isso, obrigada!